# node.js server 502 bad gateway with no errors in application logs (nginx reverse proxy setup)

Tags: node.js, debugging, nginx, error-handling, reverse-proxy

I have a node.js (+Express) application hosted on ubuntu 16.04 machine serving a http web application and an nginx reverse proxy serving a https server (proxying requests to my node application to port 8080). When somebody is using my web app via the browser, after a couple of requests sent back and forth between the browser and the server, the applications stops responding and returns a 502 bad gateway response.

From what I read about upstream errors in nginx, the fault lies probably with the node.js application and bad error handling - server crashing and restarting. Unfortunately there is nothing in my node logs, the logs just "fall silent" at one point and log nothing. So I am frankly at a loss at how to debug the issue. I do have an error handler set up in my node app - setup as a middleware, the last to be used by the express app.

One other thing I find very weird is that when I get a 502 bad gateway in chrome (after 2mins of app hanging/loading), the site just won't load or reload. But when I open the site in chrome incognito, I manage to open the landing page, go to login page and send a POST request with login details. Only after that do the app hang (and send a 502 bad gateway, after about 2mins). And when I use chrome incognito the logs do show some request, the last one is usually
 `GET /js/24.a34f9a13b9032f4d89b4.chunk.js HTTP/1.1` then the log goes silent again. (So express never receives the POST request with login data)

Could anyone point me in the right direction to find and fix that problem? Please be patient with me, since I am mostly a beginner in web development.

Below is the error from nginx logs:

`2018/03/28 17:34:45 [error] 19696#19696: *2078 connect() failed (111:         Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.89.32.129, server: dashboard.hsseowayds.com, request: "GET /assets/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8080/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css", host: "dashboard.hsseowayds.com", referrer: "https://dashboard.hsseowayds.com/"
2018/03/28 17:34:50 [error] 19696#19696: *2036 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 91.89.32.129, server: dashboard.hsseowayds.com, request: "POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/login", host: "dashboard.hsseowayds.com", referrer: "https://dashboard.hsseowayds.com/"
2018/03/28 17:34:50 [error] 19696#19696: *2036 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 91.89.32.129, server: dashboard.hsseowayds.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "dashboard.hsseowayds.com", referrer: "https://dashboard.hsseowayds.com/auth/login"`

I also did a tcpdump for ports 80, 443 and 8080 for all interfaces (both ethernet and loopback) when I was using chrome incognito during the issues with the server and tried to use wireshark to figure out what was wrong, but had no success. (I also used wireshark to caputure the traffic between my computer and the server which yielded nothing helpful to me either). The tcpdump command I used was:
`sudo tcpdump -l -w tcpdump_any_fail_1832.pcap -tttt -i any -s0 port 80 or port 443 or port 8080`

If anyone wants to have a look, here is a screenshot from wireshark and the .pcap file I can send you privately (I changed the login data inside), since I don't think I can attach it here:
[wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBtlz.jpg)

And this is my nginx file from sites-availables:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dashboard.hsseowayds.com dashboard.hsseowayds.com;
    return 301 https://dashboard.hsseowayds.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name dashboard.hsseowayds.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/dashboard.hsseowayds.com/rapidSSL.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dashboard.hsseowayds.com/ssl_private_key.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 180m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DHE+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/cert/dhparam.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    underscores_in_headers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection              '';
        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 160s;
        proxy_send_timeout   600;
        proxy_read_timeout   600;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your file which proxies your site within the nginx "sites-available" directory?

Comment: @dvsoukup, done